# how to use multi provider version in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, provider

just like to know if it's possible to use multiple provider versions?
for example, when deploy resources with terraform Azure provider
part of resources is deployed with azurerm provider version 2.55.0, rest deployed with provider version 2.99.0

is that possible? I tried the code below, but didn't work

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.29, < 2.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.99.0"
      #     version = "~> 2.64"

    }

     azurermlatest = {
       source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
       version = "= 3.3.0"
    }

  }
}
```

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azurermlatest: provider registry registry.terraform.io
│ does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurermlatest
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when using a module.
│ To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/azurermlatest, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
```

I know there was a constraint that terraform will use the newest version that meets the configuration's version constraints. but in the latest document, the statement is already removed, so not sure if multi version provider is possible or not as of now

https://www.terraform.io/language/configuration-0-11/providers

update:

the error disappeared after cleaning up the cache and backend
but multi provider still not work, the code and error as below
would someone check and help?

main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.29, < 2.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.99.0"
      #     version = "~> 2.64"

    }

    azurermlatest = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "= 3.3.0"
    }

  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "old"
  features {}

}

provider "azurermlatest" {
  alias = "latest"
  features {}

}


module "data" {
  source         = "../modules"
  rg_settings    = var.rg_settings
  vnet_settings  = var.vnet_settings
  nsg_settings   = var.nsg_settings
  lb_settings    = var.lb_settings
  vm_settings    = var.vm_settings
  avset_settings = var.avset_settings

  providers = {
    azurerm.old    = azurerm.old
    azurerm.latest = azurermlatest.latest
  }

}
```

modules

```
locals {
  lb_frontend_config_public_ip = {
    ipa = {
      name                = "test"
      resource_group_name = "test"
      location            = "eastasia"
      allocation_method   = "Static"
    }
  }

  lb_frontend_config_public_ip_latest = {
    ipa = {
      name                = "test2"
      resource_group_name = "test"
      location            = "eastasia"
      allocation_method   = "Static"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {

  provider                = azurerm.old
  for_each                = local.lb_frontend_config_public_ip
  name                    = each.value.name
  resource_group_name     = each.value.resource_group_name
  location                = each.value.location
  allocation_method       = each.value.allocation_method
  sku                     = lookup(each.value, "sku", "Standard")
  sku_tier                = lookup(each.value, "sku_tier", "Regional")
  ip_version              = lookup(each.value, "ip_version", "IPv4")
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = lookup(each.value, "idle_timeout_in_minutes", null)
  domain_name_label       = lookup(each.value, "domain_name_label", null)
  reverse_fqdn            = lookup(each.value, "reverse_fqdn", null)
  availability_zone       = lookup(each.value, "availability_zone", null)
  # edge_zone               = lookup(each.value, "edge_zone", null)
  tags                = lookup(each.value, "tags", null)
  public_ip_prefix_id = lookup(each.value, "public_ip_prefix_id", null)
  ip_tags             = lookup(each.value, "ip_tags", null)
}


resource "azurerm_public_ip" "piplatest" {

  provider                = azurerm.latest
  for_each                = local.lb_frontend_config_public_ip_latest
  name                    = each.value.name
  resource_group_name     = each.value.resource_group_name
  location                = each.value.location
  allocation_method       = each.value.allocation_method
  sku                     = lookup(each.value, "sku", "Standard")
  sku_tier                = lookup(each.value, "sku_tier", "Regional")
  ip_version              = lookup(each.value, "ip_version", "IPv4")
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = lookup(each.value, "idle_timeout_in_minutes", null)
  domain_name_label       = lookup(each.value, "domain_name_label", null)
  reverse_fqdn            = lookup(each.value, "reverse_fqdn", null)
  # availability_zone       = lookup(each.value, "availability_zone", null)
  zones = lookup(each.value, "availability_zone", null)

  # edge_zone               = lookup(each.value, "edge_zone", null)
  tags                = lookup(each.value, "tags", null)
  public_ip_prefix_id = lookup(each.value, "public_ip_prefix_id", null)
  ip_tags             = lookup(each.value, "ip_tags", null)
}
```

error:

```
 Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on ..\modules\load_balancer.tf line 63, in resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip":
│   63:   availability_zone       = lookup(each.value, "availability_zone", null)
│
│ An argument named "availability_zone" is not expected here.
```

seems like terraform still using provider 3.3.0 even I set the provider to azurerm.old

Comment: Your required_providers is correct and it works in current TF.  So your issue is not related to the code you presented.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code on my end and your providers block seems to be set correctly.

The only way to reproduce your error was if the source is updated to reference an invalid path:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "= 1.1.3"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.99.0"
    }
    azurermlatest = {
       source  = "hashicorp/azurermlatest"
       version = "= 3.3.0"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

So the error definitely comes from somewhere else. I'd suggest reviewing your code, maybe cleaning up the cache or the `.terraform` folder and any other temp files and re-running `terraform init` and `plan` again.

See [this page](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements#best-practices-for-provider-versions) for more information about the providers best practice.

Comment: the error is gone after cleaning up the cache, but  multi version provider still not work, i already update my code, could you please help check? thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the `azurerm_public_ip` argument be `zones` instead of `availability_zone` ?

Comment: for version 2.99.0. it's availability_zone, for version 3.3.0, it's zones, I assigned the provider version to 2.99.0 with provider = azurerm.old, availability_zone should work in that case, but terraform still use version 3.3.0, that's why the error throw out

Comment: Do you have any document that says it's `availability_zone` for older version? Or did you manage to successfully make it work with availability_zone before? I went as far back as v1.1.4 and can see that `zones` was added then. See https://github.com/nordbergm/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/66d6d1e9bd679ab8d3713f0031dad7b64966fdfb/website/docs/r/public_ip.html.markdown

Answer (score 0):

Your entire concept and answers provided are totally wrong.
The `providers` block in your example works only because the two constraints:

- `>=2.99.0`
- `=3.3.0`

are in fact equal to `=3.3.0` and terraform is downloading it.

Naming the same provider with different key in `required_providers` block is NOT a good practice, and in fact Terraform will remind you of that while doing `terraform init`:

"Provider hashicorp/azurerm with the local name "azurermlatest" was previously required as "azurerm". A provider can only be required once within required_providers."

If you wold do the constraint that would not allow Terraform to download version higher than 2.x (like you have commented out), you would see the error of:

"Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azurerm: no available releases match the given constraints 2.99.0, 3.3.0"

In theory, you could copy the `azure` provider to an in-house private registry, rename it, and use its name in every resource name, but this sounds horrible and wrong.

Better idea is to split the project into two and run the "legacy" code with older provider version, and the new code with fresh provider version. You can combine those two projects using `remote_state` objects (https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data).